# Namespace for [DataContract]

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I can't find the namespace to use for `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` elements. According to what I've found, it seems that adding the following should be enough, but in my case it is not.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyNamespace {

    [DataContract]
    public class Tuple<T1, T2> {
            // A custom implementation of a Tuple
            //...
            //...
        }
}
```

And the error I get:

> The type or namespace name 'DataContract' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I not using the right namespaces?

Comment: Using VS 2017, compiler error, can't build, no message in errors list or any indication at all.  No syntax coloring of DataContract, nothing.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 Right click on your project Add/Reference. In the dialog find System.Runtime.Serialization and make checkbox cheked state. Then Press  "Ok"

Answer (score 445, accepted):

`DataContractAttribute` Class is in the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace.

You should add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`. That assembly isn't referenced by default though. To add the reference to your project you have to go to References -> Add Reference in the Solution Explorer and add an assembly reference manually.

Comment: ....and that assembly isn't referenced by default, so you have to go to `References -> Add Reference` in Solution Explorer and add an assembly reference...

Comment: That's it, I didn't have the reference in my solution! I thought that if a reference were needed, it would get me an error on the line `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`. I guess I was wrong :)

Comment: Ugh. Why on Earth doesn't it error on the `using` statement? That seems to make sense to me.

Comment: I guess that's because another dll is using that namespace (otherwise you would get an error)

Comment: Thank you!  None of Microsoft's example doc mentions this.

Comment: If you are using VisualStudio you'll need to exit VS and reopen it before it will recognize newly referenced packages.

Answer (score 7):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx

DataContractAttribute is in System.Runtime.Serialization namespace and you should reference System.Runtime.Serialization.dll. It's only available in .Net >= 3

Answer (score 7):

In visual studio for .Net 4.0 framework,

1. Try to add new reference to project.
2. On .Net Tab, Search `System.Runtime.Serialization`.
3. Now, you can use `using System.Runtime.Serialization`. And the error will not be shown.

Answer (score 5):

[DataContract] and [DataMember] attribute are found in System.ServiceModel namespace which is in System.ServiceModel.dll .

System.ServiceModel uses the System and System.Runtime.Serialization namespaces to serialize the datamembers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll  in the reference

Answer (score 0):

First, I add the references to my Model, then I use them in my code. There are two references you should add:

> using System.ServiceModel;
>   using System.Runtime.Serialization;

then, this problem was solved in my program. I hope this answer can help you. Thanks.