# managing property names returned in json from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working with ASP.NET web api where I return a Model object like following from my REST operation:

Product with properties: `Name, Id, Description, etc.....`

When this is converted to a `JSON` object, it outputs it with property names above.

To cut down the payload returned from the web api operation, is there any way I can change the properties in the JSON object like for example `Desc` for `Description`. I could change the Model object but the property names would not make sense then!

Answer (score 25):

The easy way to do this is through a data contract.  [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx), but basically, it involves two annotations on your model.  It also allows you to ignore anything you don't want serialized.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo {  //Your model class

   [DataMember(Name="bar-none")]  //This also allows you to use chars like '-'
   public string bar {get; set;}

   [IgnoreDataMember]  //Don't serialize this one
   public List<string> fuzz { get; set;}

}
```

Comment: This was perfect for my purposes, which were the same as OP's.

Comment: You might also need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization which isn't added by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401795/namespace-for-datacontract

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using http://automapper.org/ on the asp.net side to map your full objects, to more lightweight ones. Might be overkill for just one or two small objects, but if you have a bunch to do this can save you some time (free and open source to boot).