# Type or namespace for datacontract

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got the same problem as this post - [Namespace for [DataContract]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401795/namespace-for-datacontract) however the solution isn't the same.

I've already got System.Runtime.Serialization referenced in the project and i'm targeting .net4. This was the answer for the previous question

Interestingly VS color coding seems to think this is valid but it does not compile.

[image]

References:

[image]

Error messages are:

> The type or namespace name 'DataContractAttribute' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Same for DataContract, DataMemberAttribute, DataMember.

The project i'm using defines a number of classes which i'm now wanting to serialize as data contracts and make available for another project. So this is not a WCF project but will be used in one later.

Thinking it may work I closed project and re-opened but still doesn't work.

Comment: have you added the using statement for System.Runtime.Serialization?

Comment: Looks like this error is related to another class or project in solution. There's no any magic in adding reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`. Look carefully at error message, which class it is related to.

Comment: There is no color coding if there isn't a using statement; yes it's there. Double clicking on the error message takes me directly to the lines noted above. Exact same code replicated in another project works. Both projects are DLL's; I'm wanting to use the first in the second rather than re-invent & maintain a pile of classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doh ! problem is exactly the same as the previous question. Two projects in this one solution; references added only to one of the projects; and the file in error was being used by both projects.

Comment: *+1* - just did exactly the same thing!