# Empty data being returned by entity using webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following entity

```
People
---------
People_id
report_id
last_name
first_name
----------
Navigation properties 
people1     
people2
people_location
```

Context Class

```
 public partial class myPeople : DbContext
    {
        public myPeople()
            : base("name=myPeople")
        {
            base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<people_location> project_status { get; set; }
        public DbSet<people> people { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model Class generated by EF

---

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = false)]
    [Serializable]
    public partial class person
    {
        public people()
        {
            this.people1 = new HashSet<person>();
            this.project_discussion = new HashSet<people_location>();
        }

        public int people_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> report_id { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<people> people1 { get; set; }
        public virtual people people2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<people_location> people_location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Web API controller

```
// GET api/personLoc
 public List<people> Getpeople()
    {
        return db.people.AsEnumerable().ToList();
    }
```

When I run the API to make sure it is working

```
../api/personLoc/
```

I just get bunch of empty records

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

I believe the issue is decoration of

```
[DataContract(IsReference = false)]
    [Serializable]
```

When I remove this from class I get following exception

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>An error has occurred.</Message>Object graph for type 'CMEApp.Entities.person' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.</ExceptionMessage>

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a circular dependency. You need to mark IsReference true in your Person DataContract as follows,

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [Serializable]
    public partial class person
```

You can get further information about IsRefernce attribute from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There is a similar stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392466/2390020)

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.