# If Entity Framework data obtained via navigation properties isn't empty, it causes error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I'm having `WCF` service, with included `.edmx` file, generated from existing data base. At the begging there were problem, that at `WCF` level data was successfully obtained and sent, but in `MVC Controller` appeared  error that connection was closed, as I understood that was because of  `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;` , when I changed it to false, everything seemed to work fine, until I've tried to get data from multiple tables, which are linked.

So, `.edmx` file, there are auto generated classes `UserProfile` and `Roles`

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.webpages_Roles = new HashSet<webpages_Roles>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class webpages_Roles
{
    public webpages_Roles()
    {
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in Database there is table which consist of

```
UserId
RoleId
```

As I understood, this is called `Navigation Property`. My problem is - when I'm trying to send data gathered like:

```
List<UserProfile> result = Context.UserProfiles
            .Include(s => s.webpages_Roles)
            .Where(z => z.UserId == id)
            .ToList();
```

I'm receiving same error as than `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` was true. Also I've noticed that in case where `webpages_Roles Collection` is empty, everything works fine, but if there are at least one record - I'm receiving error message. Please help me, solve it.

Also, I've configured service to write exceptions, and the message was

> webpages_Roles' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to decorate `UserProfile` and `webpages_Roles` classes with
`[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` attribute

The answer was found in [this arcticle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392402/circular-references-preventing-serialization-of-object-graph)