# Is there a serialization system for .net that supports reference tracking across streams?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I would like to track object references across multiple chunks of serialized objects. The serializers I know can track references, but only to serialize one graph as a whole at once. I want to partially serialize a graph and then later serialize another part of it or update some objects from the graph.

I think the code below explains my problem quite well - I'm searching for a Serializer that would print a "Success" if it was used here.

```
[Serializable]
class TestClass
{
    public string Identifier;
    public TestClass Reference;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //some test data
        TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
        t1.Identifier = "t1";
        TestClass t2 = new TestClass();
        t2.Reference = t1;
        t2.Identifier = "t2";

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); //replace this with something that works ^^
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(1024);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, t1);
        //possibly do lots of things inbetween these two, including, 
        //but not limited to, switching streams, writing other things 
        //on the stream etc.
        formatter.Serialize(stream, t2);
        stream.Position = 0;
        object copy1 = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        object copy2 = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        if (((TestClass)copy2).Reference == copy1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My use case is essentially that I want to send objects over the network and keep the references intact. I have looked into protobuf-net and have written some workarounds around this issue, but they are getting out of hands in terms of complexity. My question is: is there a (good) serialization library that allows me to track references across one call of the deserialization method? Or am I missing some simple technique to archieve this with existing serializers? Or do I have to write such a thing by myself?

**EDIT:** Clarification: This is networking for a game, so speed and compactness are an issue. That means XML/JSON serializers are a rather bad alternative.

Answer (score 1):

DataContracts can provide this functionality.  Basically you would decorate a class with `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]`. Also, the good news about DataContracts is that they're baked into WCF by default, so you'll already have a communication layer to go along with your project.

See this question for more.

[Circular references preventing serialization of object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392402/circular-references-preventing-serialization-of-object-graph)

And here's some more information on MSDN's site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Is there a binary version of that serializer?

Comment: Not of the DataContractSerializer, no.