# The type or namespace name 'DataServiceStreamLink' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Services.Client'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am Implementing Windows Azure Active Directory to establish a connection to API

The type or namespace name 'DataServiceStreamLink' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Services.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceStreamLink thumbnailPhoto)
{//some thing}

For this I addded a name space using System.Runtime.Serialization;
After that removed this reference and added System.Runtime.Serialization.dll still it's showing same error how can I handle this Error?

Comment: Do you have a reference to Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll? It's not clear why you're adding a using directive for `System.Runtime.Serialization` when it's not in that namespace...

Comment: I followed this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401795/namespace-for-datacontract

Comment: But that's for a completely different type... it's got nothing to do with DataServiceStreamLink. Again, do you have a reference to `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll`? That's the assembly which contains `DataServiceStreamLink`.

Comment: Yes I added this Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll Reference manually

Comment: In that case it should be fine.

Comment: I SOLVED MY SELF    By Adding latest version of 
System.Data.Services.Client
Version 5.6.0.0

Comment: I encountered this when using assembly reference `System.Data.Services.Client.dll` but resolved it when changing to `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll`.