# How to access ServiceStack based web service from visual studio webform

Tags: c#, webforms, servicestack

I'm having trouble understanding how to consume an existing ServiceStack based web service (https://cert.web.transaction.transactionexpress.com/TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/). I am using a standard vstudio .net 4.6 aspnet website c# form.

I tried adding the [base service uri](https://cert.web.transaction.transactionexpress.com/TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/) as a service reference to my existing project (Website > Add Service Reference > URI) but on building my solution I receive error: [Error: failed to generate code for the service reference. Cannot import wsdl:portType...].

I would like to think that I can interact with this service without manually building object definitions, so I must be missing a step.

Two questions:
1.  Has anyone else worked with this particular service? Or can you suggest how to generate object definitions from this service?
2.  Am I incorrectly assuming that generating the object definitions will give me full VStudio intellisense on my httpclient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a ServiceStack Web Service you can use [C# Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference) to generate a Typed API in C# which you can use with [ServiceStack's C# Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client).

The `BaseUrl` for this Service is:

https://cert.web.transaction.transactionexpress.com/TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/

So if you [install ServiceStack VS](http://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice#step-1-download-and-install-servicestackvs) from VS.NET Extension gallery:

[image]

You can create a Typed C# API by clicking on **Add ServiceStack Reference** on your project:

[image]

Then you can use the Typed DTOs with ServiceStack's generic Service Clients, e.g:

```
var baseUrl = "https://cert.web.transaction.transactionexpress.com/TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/";
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
var response = client.Post(new CreateCustomReport { ... });
```

Comment: OK thanks for the quick response.  I add the SS Reference but the generated class has a series of errors beginning with "Type or namespace name 'DataContractAttribute' could not be found (are you missing...)", "'DataContract' could not be found ... etc.

Comment: @MTAdmin That's [.NET `[DataContract]` Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you need to [add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401828/85785)

Comment: OK, maybe I'm getting closer to the question I should be asking...VS (2015/2017) doesn't have a menu option to add an SS Reference in an existing aspnet site.  I tried to work around that by adding a separate SS project to my existing solution.  Having both projects in one solution causes VS to indicate errors with the DataContract in the generated class file.  So - is there any way to add a SS Reference to an existing aspnet website?

Comment: @MTAdmin My answer shows how to Add a ServiceStack Reference to an existing project. I don't know what your error you're getting but it sounds like a dependency conflict. You can add a reference without a UI by including [TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/types/csharp](https://cert.web.transaction.transactionexpress.com/TransFirst.Transaction.Web/api/types/csharp) source file in your project and manually adding a reference to [ServiceStack.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client) NuGet package.

Comment: Adding the static types source file answers my question.  I suppose this introduces the possibility of future source changes breaking my offline types but I can live with this for now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MTAdmin The source file never changes unless you update the service reference or download the latest copy. If they only make [the recommended backwards-compatible versionable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413091/85785) the old DTO's and Service Requests will continue to work despite not using the latest DTOs.